# What is the log for canceled or terminated queries?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I terminated a long running query using select `pg_terminate_backend(pid)`.

Can I find any log for this?

Comment: @Ken white. I just want to know the timestamps

Comment: Yes.. i want to know when it was terminated?

Answer (score 0):

Such events are logged automatically unless you change `log_min_error` to `panic`, because they cause a `FATAL` error (the connection is terminated).

Just look into the PostgreSQL log file.
The log entry will look like this:

```
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```